# Does the ContactsContract.Contacts._ID remains?

Tags: android, contacts

I access the contacts list this way:

```
CursorLoader oCursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MyContext, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
Cursor oCursor = oCursorLoader.loadInBackground();

int contactId = oCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
int name = oCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

oCursor.moveToFirst();
if(oCursor.isAfterLast()==false) {
    do {
        String sId = oCursor.getString(contactId);
        String phName = oCursor.getString(name);

        ...more code...
    } while (oCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

I want to save the ID for a contact in a database to do some processing later on. For example, I want to save latest contacts called.

My question is:
Does the ID for a contact remains the same even if the contact is modified?
For example, if I save in the database the id "44" por user "Boss", does that ID remains the same even if the device is rebooted, or contact is modified (for example its name or phone number or email address)?

Comment: yes `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` is readonly and will not be changed if rebooted/modified. Look for accessing contacts https://github.com/AvinashChowdary/Contacts

Comment: Well, I have discovered the opposite. If contacts are synced, they could change the id. In fact, I read some complex look-up-id or similar to "try" to recover the new id. Very confusing.